# Refresh Token for Microsoft Azure AD IdP Enterprise connection

Tags: auth0

I have figured out how to request scopes from the IdP to uses its services, in my case the `Microsoft GraphQL`.

However that token seems to expire quickly and when I try and add the `offline access` scope it does not show up in the scopes even though the Azure app has permission to grant that scope.

How do you refresh the IdP token? I'm afraid this may not be possible so please recommend alternative solutions if that's the case.  I might need to have an addition login inside the app to auth with MS directly... slightly annoying user flow but will be fine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75576011/10978688

Comment: I believe that just gets a refresh token for auth0 not the IdP no?